# Add dynamically a panel into a SplitPanel

Tags: java, swing, jsplitpane

I'm creating a GUI for a project but I'm a newbie of swing so I obviously got problems:

My AppFrame is formed by:

JFrame --> ContentPane --> SplitPane

The splitpane left component is used for a menu, the right component should host differents JPane according to the menu's button.
I press the "Products" button? I wish to see MyProductsJPanel and so on.

The splitpane is created and added in the Jframe's constructor, how I can access and modify it at runtime?

Is a wrong layout?

PS: I use WindowBuilder plugin for eclipse, wich generates most part of the code of course.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: You need some kind of reference to the split pane in order to be able to add content to it.  This would suggest that you need to pass a reference of it to the menu, or, for a better solution, have the menu generate events when the user selects a menu which notifies a controller of some kind which can make the appropriate updates

Comment: @MadProgrammer thank you, I solved! Solution was easier than I thought: I added an event listener on the mouse button wich modify the right comp!

Comment: *"I'm sorry for all this questions.."* This is a Q&A site. It would be pretty pointless without questions (and less interesting with only a few questions). *"..and for my not-so-good english."* Your use of English is good enough to explain the problem, and that is the important thing. Thanks for describing the problem in the only language I understand. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to @MadProgrammer contribution I'm able to give a solution:

In the JFrame constructor I added a listener for every button of the menu.
In the listener:

```
public MouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0){
   splitPane.remove(splitPane.getRightComponent()); //Useless?
   mySplitPane.setRightComponent(new OneOfMyButtonRelatedPane());
}
```

Works and solve my question